# SAP Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2010 add summary total to report footer to a desktop application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

In an existing Visual Studio 2010 desktop application that uses existing Crystal reports, there is a summary amount that appears in the report footer section of the current crystal report. The current calculation is usually close but it changes every time the crystal report is executed. Note I am new to working with Crystal reports and no one else at my company knows how to work with crystal reports. Since I have not been to figure how I can modify the calculation so that the amount is correct, I would like to create a new calculation for this field.

I have tried the following:

1. Running totals placed into the report footer but I get the result of #####.
2. I have tried formula fields placed into the report footer but I get the result  of #######.
3. I have tried to use insert summary of the purchase amount in the report footer and I get the ##### message.
4. I have followed the directions in the following link and it did not work:

http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=111265

Thus can you tell me how to summarize the  purchase amount from every detail that is placed into the report so the total appears in the report footer? Also I may need to also reset the value to zero everytime the report is executed. **I am not certain if I need this option.

Comment: I am not getting this, does everytime you change summary, you get "#####"? means hash is being displayed? If yes, then i can tell you what to do

Answer (score 0):

Look the approach you are following is completely fine and correct. You can use either way to get the summary. The best will be put the Summary field in the Report Footer.

Whenever you place any numerical summary field in any section, or any numeric value fields in crystal, make sure you allot proper width to the text object or the formula field placed in report.

In case, the value is in millions, and width is less and only proper to show thousands, you will get "####" rather than the value. This indicates you have increase the width of the field.

Let me know if this helps, and in case you face any other issue?

Comment: what do you do to accept as answered? I clicked on vote and that is not marked as answered? What do you click on?

Comment: There must be a tick mark on the left of every answer. When one accepts the best, click on it and it will be green colored. (Just below voteup and down symbols)

Comment: I do not see 'Just below voteup and down symbols'. I only see tabs for active, oldestm and votes.

Comment: Click on the grey tick mark, its as simple. It shows if you are logged in, and you have asked the question, in case you don't see, there is a glitch.